# FactorEvaluationError fixed effects model python

Tags: python, linearmodels

I'm trying to run a fixed-effects model using panel data, here is a sample of my data:

| type | id | time | treatment | employment | wage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 30.0 | NaN |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 3.5 | 4.30 |
| 2 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 6.5 | NaN |
| 3 | 2 | 1 | 0 | NaN | 4.45 |
| 4 | 3 | 0 | 1 | 3.0 | NaN |

And this is the code I am using:

```
model_fe = PanelOLS.from_formula('employment ~ wage + EntityEffects', final_data)
```

However, I'm getting the error

```
FactorEvaluationError: Unable to evaluate factor `employment`. [NameError: `employment` is not present in the dataset or evaluation context.]
```

I'm unsure why this is happening, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I was having a similar problem and, as far as I can tell so far, `linearmodels` seems to require a time index, even if you're not using TimeEffects. 

My error went away after I added a time index (2nd element of my MultiIndex)

Answer (score 1):

Panel OLS usually is on muli-index, the first one being your type or id, and the second index needs to be time. So if you just `set_index()` your code will work:

```
final_data = final_data.set_index(['type', 'time'])
model_fe = PanelOLS.from_formula('employment ~ wage + EntityEffects', final_data)
```